# About the memory usage of Mobilenet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, mobilenet

I'm building MobileNetV1 with Pytorch and had my memory ran out every time I train the model. (The pytorch log "Killed!" and suddenly crashed).
This is my code

> Config file: (yaml)

```
n_gpu: 0

arch: 
    type: MobileNet
    args: 
        in_channels: 3
        num_classes: 26
    
data_loader: 
    type: BallDataLoader
    args:
        data_dir: data/balls/
        batch_size: 64
        shuffle: true
        validation_split: 0.2
        num_workers: 0
        resize: 
        - 224
        - 224
    
optimizer:
    type: Adam
    args:
        lr: 1.0e-2
        weight_decay: 0
        amsgrad: true
    
loss: nll_loss
metrics: 
    - accuracy
    - top_k_acc

lr_scheduler: 
    type: StepLR
    args: 
        step_size: 50
        gamma: 0.1
    

trainer: 
    epochs: 50
    save_dir: saved/
    save_period: 2
    verbosity: 2
    monitor: min val_loss
    early_stop: 10
    tensorboard: true
```

> modules.py:

```
class DepthwiseSeparableConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = None):
        super().__init__()
        if padding == None:
            padding = kernel_size // 2
        self.depth_wise_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, in_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, groups= in_channels)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(in_channels)
        self.point_wise_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, (1,1), 1, 0)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.depth_wise_conv(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.point_wise_conv(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        return x
```

> model.py

```
class MobileNet(ImageNet):
    def __init__(self, in_channels = 3, num_classes = 1000):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.convs = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 32, kernel_size= 3, padding= 1, stride = 1 ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(inplace = True),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(32, 64),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(64, 128, stride = 2),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(128, 128),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(128, 256),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(256, 256),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(256, 512, stride = 2),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(512, 512),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(512, 512),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(512, 512),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(512, 512),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(512, 512),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(512, 1024, stride = 1),
            DepthwiseSeparableConv(1024, 1024, stride= 2),
            nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
        )
        self.fc = nn.Linear(1024, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 1024)
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x, dim = 1)
        return x
```

So I found a model from https://github.com/jmjeon94/MobileNet-Pytorch, and it worked. After hours I still can't find out why this happened as the models are nearly identical, and since the architect of mobilenet is farely light, this shouldn't take much space to run I supposed. Is there any chance that this is because of the python interpreter or there are actually something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your batch size. Try using smaller batch size like 32,16,8,4,2.

Comment: I used the same configs for both model... So it's not about the batch size, right...?

Comment: And of course, yes, with batch size of 16, 32 or when I resize the input images to (48 x 48) my model worked too, but it should work with the default configs as the model i found on github, right?

Comment: I think it's because of batch size only. Test it with batch size 4. It will work

Comment: I think you might misunderstood here. I apologize for not making it clear. The problem is not why my model didn't work. Yes, **it worked with smaller batch size or smaller images**. But the think I'm asking here is why my model didn't work while an identical model did. I'm just curious about how this problem might happen.

Comment: They have specified the device as 'cpu'. Try keeping the same, they your model will run with the same config.

Comment: I keeping it the same tho...Still didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I delete the line `nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 32, kernel_size= 3, padding= 1, stride = 1 )` and rewrite the same and the code ran. Still don't know why but it seem to be the interpreter or the text editor which cause the error. Thank you for attending.
And special thanks to Mr. @Anmol Narang for your efford, I'm very appreciated.